# not able to change logo on top of browser (fav icon)

Tags: html, css

i have a website , i changed the fav icon from the website and replaced it with mine, changed the size and format and everything as the previous one. but the website still shows the previous icon and its not updating with the new one, even though the old icon is deleted. below is what i did to give the icon

```html
    <meta name="author" content="Suave Digital">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/images/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets/images/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets\images\favicon-32x32.png">
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try to refresh the page with `ctrl+f5`?

Comment: Look in the network console to see if it give 404 - also be consistent on the direction of the slashes. You have / and \

Comment: @vishnu thanks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Favicon wont update easily because of browser cache:

Clear your browser cache and refresh the page

Or

Hover the mouse on your website tab and reload the window

Comment: Really? Worth an answer?